# Is my answer for this truth table & boolean expression correct?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was given the following boolean diagram:

[image: Logical diagram showing inputs and output]

I had to come out with the truth table and the simplified expression.  I need help to check if my answers are correct below.

[image: Truth table and boolean expression simplification]

Comment: What is the question and what are your answers? Also, "below"?

Comment: Well the equivalence transitions are right, but I haven't checked the truth table also what exactly are you asking ?

Comment: You could verify such things in EXCEL and see the answer below

Answer (score 2):

You've done a fine job on your truth table and in the simplification of $X$.

A quick way to check and show that your truth table is consistent with your simplification is to note, from the truth-table, that $X$ is true, or (1), in only one of the eight rows, when $A$ is false, and both $B, C$ are true.

This means $X$ holds exactly when $\overline A$ is true,  AND $B$ is true,  AND $C$ is true: $$X = \overline ABC$$.

Answer (score 1):

I have verified it in EXCEL and see the answer below

[image]

TRUE = 1

FALSE = 0

Your relation is right and the truth table is right too

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 0):

If the question is: "Provide the Boolean expression from the above Truth Table", is the answer c) still correct?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1764717)